# OpenCV countNonZero channels assertion

Tags: opencv

I want to count how many pixels of a color image are equal to a specific color. I wrote a code similar to this:

```
  cv::Mat image(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
  cv::randu(image, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
  cv::Vec3b color(55, 30, 145);
  std::cout << cv::countNonZero(cv::Mat(image == color)) << std::endl;
```

but throws:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/core/src/count_non_zero.dispatch.cpp:124: error: (-215:Assertion failed) cn == 1 in function 'countNonZero'

According to the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914) cv::countNonZero works only for single-channel arrays, so it makes sense it throws an exception. However, the following code does not throw any exception:

```
  cv::Mat image(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
  cv::randu(image, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
  cv::Vec3b color(55, 30, 145);
  std::cout << cv::countNonZero(image == color) << std::endl;
```

Why? Can I rely on the result of the last use?

Comment: so what you're saying is... wrapping the comparison in `cv::Mat()` makes a difference? I would find that odd.

Comment: Exactly. That's the only difference

Comment: if I had to speculate, it's those "matrix expressions" the C++ API of OpenCV offers (operator overloads, mostly). the result of the comparison might not be a Mat but something else, which for some reason is digested differently by countNonZero()... just a guess. might give you an idea what to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I rely on the result of the last use?

Result type of your comparison `image == color` becomes `MatExpr`.

And, in the document:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#details

`countNonZero` is shown as applicable to `MatExpr`.

---

But when you convert the `MatExpr` to `Mat` (by `cv::Mat(image == color)`), the result becomes 3 channels
(I can't find the clear description about this point...), So, problem occurs as you said.

Comment: Also, the link says: > The result of comparison is an 8-bit single channel mask